# R: fill a new column in a data frame with a value by matching variables in reverse

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologize for the title of this question. I can't figure out how a good way to briefly describe what I want to do.

I have something like this, with >8000 rows:

```
x  y value_xy
A  B   7 
A  C   2 
B  A   3
B  C   6 
C  A   2
C  B   1
```

I want to create a new column, value_yx, that looks like this:

```
x  y value_xy value_yx
A  B   7         3 
A  C   2         2  
B  A   3         7
B  C   1         1
C  A   2         2
C  B   1         1
```

For each value of x and y, I want to have a new column that finds the value of y to x (as y appears later in the x column). Sometimes these values are equal, other times they aren't.

I have explored using for loops, ave(), and several other functions, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was beat to it but an alternative solution with mapply

```
df$value_yx = mapply(function(x_flip, y_flip) df[df$x == y_flip & df$y == x_flip,]$value_xy, df$x, df$y)

#  x y value_xy value_yx
#1 A B        7        3
#2 A C        2        2
#3 B A        3        7
#4 B C        6        1
#5 C A        2        2
#6 C B        1        6
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `merge`. The `by.x` and `by.y` arguments specify columns to be matched, and here the order of matching columns is reversed in `by.y`:

```
merge(x = df, y = df, by.x = c("x", "y"), by.y = c("y", "x"))
#   x y value_xy.x value_xy.y
# 1 A B          7          3
# 2 A C          2          2
# 3 B A          3          7
# 4 B C          6          1
# 5 C A          2          2
# 6 C B          1          6
```

Comment: The value under column value_xy depends on the relationship between x and y. How would I split x and y into two separate data frames without losing that value?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean. Something like this: `df[ , c("x", "value_xy")]; df[ , c("y", "value_xy")]`?

Answer (score 1):

`xtabs` will return a value-matrix that can be indexed by a two-column, character-valued matrix formed from the first two columns and are probably factors (hence the need for the `as.character()`-conversion:

```
> dfrm$value_yx <- xtabs(value_xy~x+y, dfrm)[ 
                                    sapply(dfrm[2:1],as.character) ]
> dfrm
  x y value_xy value_yx
1 A B        7        3
2 A C        2        2
3 B A        3        7
4 B C        6        1
5 C A        2        2
6 C B        1        6
```

--- See what is being indexed

```
> xtabs(value_xy~x+y, dfrm)
   y
x   A B C
  A 0 7 2
  B 3 0 6
  C 2 1 0
```